# Размытие текста при анимации

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При применении анимации до окончания Storyboard текст остается растянутым и размытым как на картинке. Если нажать `Alt`, то все становится нормальным

Анимация:

```
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="1">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.1000000" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.2000000" Value="0.45"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.3000000" Value="0.1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.4000000" Value="0.75"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.5000000" Value="0.3"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6000000" Value="0.75"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.7000000" Value="0.22"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.8000000" Value="0.92"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.9000000" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.2000000" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-45"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="0">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.023"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="1">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.SkewX)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="57"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="0">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="1">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-76.993"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="0">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Элемент:

```
<Grid x:Name="Header" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="91" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#116d6d6d" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding VideoElement.Header, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontFamily="{StaticResource BoldFont}"
                               FontSize="45" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
</Grid>
```

При этом точно такая же анимация на точно таком же элементе на этом экране работает прекрасно.

Как можно исправить это проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы избавиться от этого эффекта, необходимо начинать анимацию не с `00:00:00`, а немного сдвинуть вперед. Достаточно на 1 миллисекунду, то есть `KeyTime="00:00:00.01"`, тогда все работает как надо. Насколько я понял, то этот какой-то баг в системе анимаций UWP, либо так себя ведут анимации после `Freeze()`